# How to vote app reviews Helpful not Helpful in App Store?

Tags: app-store, ios10, ios11, review

Has anyone figured out how to vote Helpful or unhelpful for the reviews in the Apple App Store on your mobile phone. How do you get a review to the top of the reviews ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently there is a way to accomplish this. I had to google a bit i found that, by using 3D Touch, you can press and hold over a review on the AppStore and a menu pops up. You can select Helpful, not Helpful or report a concern. This is a great feature available on iOS 10 and above.

[image: please see this screenshot i found.]

Answer (score -1):

There is no option to vote a review for mark helpful or not .
you can install application and you can post your review and rating on the Apple App Store only.